# Edit bashrc in vagrant

Tags: debian, vagrant, bash

I am using vagrant to setup a Debian VM. While installing flume, of the the steps is to add the path to the `bashrc` file. In most cases it would seem trivial as to open the file using `vi` or `nano` and adding the required lines. However the format of the `bashrc` file is very different in vagrant and since this is the very first time Im using it, i quite simple do not know how to add the lines I want to. Any help will be appreciated.

I am trying to add the following lines

```
export FLUME_HOME = "/usr/lib/flume/apache-flume-1.4.0.1-bin"
export FLUME_CONF_DIR = "$FLUME_HOME/conf"
export FLUME_CLASSPATH = "$FLUME_CONF_DIR"

export PATH="$FLUME_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use puppet to do this .
Install puppet forge module puppet module install puppetlabs-stdlib.

```
file_line { 'add_path':
  path  => '/home/vagrant/.bashrc',
  line  => 'export FLUME_HOME = /usr/lib/flume/apache-flume-1.4.0.1-bin'
}
```

Similarly try for other environment variable

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you could do something like that in your vagrant file:

```
$suScript = <<-'SHELL'
echo Adding new env. variables...

echo 'export FLUME_CONF_DIR = "$FLUME_HOME/conf"' >> /home/vagrant/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH=/STUFF:${PATH}:' >> /home/vagrant/.bashrc
echo 'et caetera...'
.
.
.
SHELL

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision :shell, privileged: true, inline: $suScript
  .
  .
  .
end
```